# Error using ASP.NET 3.5 Chart control within a Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater, charts

I'm getting the error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd" at runtime from my Chart control.  I have read one solution to this error message as documented here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/1dc4b352-c9a5-49dc-8f35-9b176509faa1/ but this does not solve my problem.

I have the Chart within a Repeater control, which is within an ajax UpdatePanel.  When I take the chart out of the Repeater (but leave it in the UpdatePanel), it works.  So I'm thinking it is to do with the Repeater.  Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed.  "POST" had to be added as a verb to the "add path" element under the httpHandlers section as well.